# How to find multiple instances of an object in an arraylist?

Tags: search, loops, arraylist

So I normally use a for each loop to find matches of something in an arraylist, but once it finds a match the loop stops, how do I make it continue to search and find all the matches, maybe even store the matches in a new arraylist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iterate through the entire set - push matched objects into a "vetted" arraylist ( or vector? ) and dont terminate processing of the for loop on the first match?

Comment: "search" "loops" and "arraylist" are not specific languages - what examples have you tried that aren't working ?

Comment: for (Object object : array)
{
if (object.getInt() == int)
{
return object
}
}

something like that

Comment: dont "return" --- that will short circuit the loop ( as you are already know and are experiencing ) - instead take the element that matches, store it in a scope variable that suits your needs and continue processing

Comment: so like : 
for (Object object : array) { if (object.getInt() == int) { someList.add(object); } }

Comment: oh okay, do I need to make the return type an arraylist then, instead of like an int?

Comment: Your choice really. Ideally whatever processes the object for further use should be a separate method / class (depending) for maintenance and extensibility purposes - so it's really up to you to decide that aspect.